# Windows App Certification Kit - Failed to launch App

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, app-certification-kit

I'm trying to pass WACK tests, but have problems with some tests. One is very strange for me:

```
App launch tests
Error Found: The app launch test detected the following errors:
Failed to launch App.
Impact if not fixed: An app that fails to launch presents a poor user experience, and will not be accepted by the Windows Store.
How to fix: Investigate and debug the app to identify and fix the problem.
```

I really don't know where is the problem. I tried to run tests on empty project or another app installed from windows store, but had same result. I used this instruction
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694081.aspx

Comment: Finally I decided, that there is problem with my dev pc, possibly it was configured with some restrictions for my admin user, so app could not be launched. I didn't find any working sollution how to fix configuration without reinstalling windows.